# LINQ-query select statement before order by or vise versa is better

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

I want to know which of the following 3 Linq expressions are equal, or if one is better compared to the others, and why?

```
var studentDetails1 = context.Student.OrderBy(a => a.Age).Select(s => new { s.Name, s.Age }).ToList();


var studentDetails2 = context.Student.Select(s => new { s.Name, s.Age }).OrderBy(a => a.Age).ToList();


var studentDetails3 = context.Student.OrderBy(a => a.Age).ToList().Select(s => new { s.Name, s.Age });
```

(as usual here context means DBContext and Student is a database entity having Name and Age properties)

Comment: Why don't you benchmark them?

Comment: Eric I didn't get you ..

Comment: It really annoying when I have actual question and without giving explanation just down-voting .

Comment: I like your question... Not sure why someone would downvote it. Either way, I suggest you put your different flavours of query in LINQPad and then look at the resulting SQL.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by Lukasz Rozmejit it does depend on entity framework dialect implementation. Typically first two will evaluate to same SQL. Last one will fetch unnecessary data and use only two columns.
I was recommended by database experts not to sort in database. SQL cpu time is most expensive CPU time.

```
var studentDetails1 = context.Student.Select(s => new { s.Name, s.Age }).ToList().OrderBy(a => a.Age);
```

This will do the sorting in the server instead of using CPU in database.

Answer (score 1):

It really can depend on actual linq provider implementation and in this particular example Entity framework dialect complementation.

But in general in most sane scenarios first two should behave exactly the same sorting on the server and retrieving only a projection, while the last one would fetch all Student entity data and actually create Student objects, making it worst one.